# Javascript Change Image

Tags: javascript, html, image

I have done research and I am pretty sure that I am doing exactly what I have found but my change image still doesn't work.

I am trying to make it so that when the person clicks an image the image changes:

```
<script type="javascript">
    function changeLeftImages()
    {
        document.getElementById("leftImagesWin").src="wins.png";
    }
</script>

<a href='javascript:changeLeftImages()'><img src='winsTab.png' width='54' height='50' style='margin-right: 5px;' id='leftImagesWin'></a>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `type` attribute should be `text/javascript`, not just `javascript`.

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of the attribute

```
type="javascript"
```

that is causing the problem with the JavaScript not being parsed.

Answer (score 1):

Use this in script tag:

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<script language="text/javascript">
    function changeLeftImages() {

        if (document.getElementById("leftImagesWin").src == "winsTab.png") 
        {
            document.getElementById("leftImagesWin").src = "wins.png";
        }
        else 
        {
            document.getElementById("leftImagesWin").src = "winsTab.png";
        }
    }
</script>

<p>
        <img alt="" src="winsTab.png" id="leftImagesWin" onclick="changeLeftImages()" />
</p>
```